# Access value from 2d array by searching for value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2d array called `MyUsernames`.

If I write `console.log(MyUsernames)` I see this:

```
0: {id: "5", name: "quirky.subdued"}
1: {id: "6", name: "phyllida.skeg"}
2: {id: "7", name: "duff.anarchist"}
3: {id: "9", name: "relashio.articulate"}
```

I am trying to access the `name` part of an element in the array.

I output the records in `MyUsernames` via this loop:

```
var hst = document.getElementById("usernames");

for (var i = 0; i < MyUsernames.length; i++) {  
    var un1 = MyUsernames[i].name;
    hst.innerHTML += "<li>" +"<a id="+MyUsernames[i].id + " href='#content' onclick='deleteById(this)'>" + un1 + "</a></li>";
}
```

This is the `deleteById` bit of code:

```
var deleteById = function ( self ){

    this_id = self.id;
    this_word = MyUsernames[this_id].name;

}
```

My problem is that I am sending e.g. an ID value of `9` to extract the Name `relashio.articulate`.

However, I am trying to access that by this bit of code:

```
this_word = MyUsernames[this_id].name;
```

That doesn't work, because as per the console output, the bit I want in my example would be access via:

```
MyUsernames[3].name;
```

And not:

```
MyUsernames[9].name;
```

The problem is I can't send an ID value of 3 because I only have the ID value of the record from `MyUsernames` which is 9.

Is there a way I can access the "name" part of the array, by its corresponding ID?

Comment: You probably want to convert array to object and be able to use `users['9'].name;` I hope you find posted answer useful, Good luck! [https://stackoverflow.com/a/64400342/14435535]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). You can provide a set of criteria inside a function and find will give one result back if your criteria matches.

You use it like this

```
var usernames = [];
usernames.push({id: "5", name: "quirky.subdued"});
usernames.push({id: "6", name: "phyllida.skeg"});
usernames.push({id: "7", name: "duff.anarchist"});
usernames.push({id: "9", name: "relashio.articulate"});

function findUsername(id) {
    var username = usernames.find(function(username) { return username.id === id });
    return username;
}

var user5 = findUsername("5");
document.write('Find result 1: ' + user5.name);

document.write('<br />');

var user9 = findUsername("9");
document.write('Find result 2: ' + user9.name);
```

Here my JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rtL87veq/11/

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your helpful reply. On your JsFiddle - you are passing 5 and 9 to your function, but both return the same `quirky.subdued` value?

Comment: @4532066 Thanks for seeing my error. I corrected the example

Answer (score 1):

**Convert Array to Object**

By implement User Id as primary key for new object variable you'll be able to find user via `users[9].name`

Output:

```
relashio.articulate
```

Define new object variable and do for loop ensure you marking user id as the primary key. Then, save rest of object data in same key. e.g.

```
var users = {};

        // for loop all your users in 'array'
        for (var i = 0; i < MyUsernames.length; i++) {

        // hold found user in variable
            var user = MyUsernames[i];

        // mark user id as the primary key then save rest of object data in same key
            users[user.id] = user;
        };
```

**Source Code**

```js
var MyUsernames = [{
  id: "5",
  name: "quirky.subdued"
}, {
  id: "6",
  name: "phyllida.skeg"
}, {
  id: "7",
  name: "duff.anarchist"
}, {
  id: "9",
  name: "relashio.articulate"
}];
    
    // define object variable
        var users = {};
        // for loop all your users in 'array'
        for (var i = 0; i < MyUsernames.length; i++) {
        // hold found user in variable
            var user = MyUsernames[i];
        // mark user id as the key then save rest of object data in same key
            users[user.id] = user;
        };
        
        // Print the value of key 'name' for user id '9'
        console.log(users[9].name)
```

Comment: Hi @i3z - that's really helpful. I would have marked this as the correct answer, but the other route also worked from Patrick. Your method is very smart - thank you :-)

Comment: Thank you! I am glad that helped you, happy coding =) @4532066

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) `O(n)` is an option and search the array by inner props.

```js
const usernames = [{
  id: "5",
  name: "quirky.subdued"
}, {
  id: "6",
  name: "phyllida.skeg"
}, {
  id: "7",
  name: "duff.anarchist"
}, {
  id: "9",
  name: "relashio.articulate"
}]


const target = usernames.find(({ id }) => id === "9")

console.log(target)
```

It is not supported in Internet Explorer. Consider using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if your target browser is IE9+

```js
const usernames = [{
  id: "5",
  name: "quirky.subdued"
}, {
  id: "6",
  name: "phyllida.skeg"
}, {
  id: "7",
  name: "duff.anarchist"
}, {
  id: "9",
  name: "relashio.articulate"
}]


const [target] = usernames.filter(({ id }) => id === "9")
// Filter returns an array of matches. Destructing helps to get the first match 

console.log(target)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
hst.innerHTML += "<li>" +"<a id="+MyUsernames[i].id + " href='#content' onclick='deleteById(this)'>" + un1 + "</a></li>";
```

to this:

```
hst.innerHTML += "<li>" + "<a id='" + i + "' href='#content' onclick='deleteById(this)'>" + un1 + "</a></li>";
```

Now, `self.id` will return `3`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider whether a js Map object is a more suitable structure, which may turn on whether the ordering of the collection -- and therefore the array index -- is relevant or just a side effect of your grouping. Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.

You can generate, access and manipulate a Map as follows with objs' id as the key, and obj itself as value in each Map pair.

```
    let dataMap = new Map();
    
    // Set key to id and obj to value for each Map pair
    MyUsernames.forEach(obj => dataMap.set(obj.id, obj));
    
    // Access value (obj) with key (id) of 2
    const objIdTwo = dataMap.get(2)

    // Determine whether pair with key (id) of 3 exists in Map
    const objIdThree = dataMap.has(3)

    // Remove pair with key (id) of 4 from Map
    dataMap.delete(4)
    
    // A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order — a for...of loop 
    // returns an array of [key, value] for each iteration.
    for (let [id, obj] of dataMap) {
       console.log(id + ' = ' + obj)
    }

   // If needed, Map can be converted to 2d-array
   const arr2d = Array.from(dataMap)
```